# How to create a filter for QTableWidget?

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qtableview, qsortfilterproxymodel

I'm trying to create a filter for `QTableWidget` with `QLineEdit` in PySide. I've seen some tutorials using `QSortFilterProxyModel` for C++ but couldn't understood how to do it in Python.

[image]

I need to search in 'VALUE' column.

Comment: All the Qt examples have been converted to Python. They are included in the source packages of PyQt (or PySide), which you can download [here](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download). Look for the `basicsortfiltermodel.py` example.

Comment: [PyQt5 examples](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/tree/master/examples), [PyQt4 examples](https://github.com/Werkov/PyQt4/tree/master/examples).

Answer (score 16):

A `QSortFilterProxyModel` is a proxy model, that means that you put it between the your complete data model and a view. The comment by [titusjan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34252413/how-to-create-a-filter-for-qtablewidget-in-pyside#comment56250526_34252413) is good, you can look in your local PySide/PyQt installation for `basicsortfiltermodel.py` to get an example in Python.

Also, instead of using a `QTableWidget` a `QTableView` is sufficient - you won't need the inbuilt model of `QTableWidget` anyway.

[QTableWidget:Details](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html)

> The QTableWidget class provides an item-based table view with a default model.
>
> Table widgets provide standard table display facilities for applications. The items in a QTableWidget are provided by QTableWidgetItem.
>
> If you want a table that uses your own data model you should use QTableView rather than this class.

I compiled an **very simple example** demonstrating filtering for the third column of a `QTableView`:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
window = QtGui.QWidget()

# standard item model
model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(5, 3)
model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['ID', 'DATE', 'VALUE'])
for row, text in enumerate(['Cell', 'Fish', 'Apple', 'Ananas', 'Mango']):
    item = QtGui.QStandardItem(text)
    model.setItem(row, 2, item)

# filter proxy model
filter_proxy_model = QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel()
filter_proxy_model.setSourceModel(model)
filter_proxy_model.setFilterKeyColumn(2) # third column

# line edit for filtering
layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(window)
line_edit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
line_edit.textChanged.connect(filter_proxy_model.setFilterRegExp)
layout.addWidget(line_edit)

# table view
table = QtGui.QTableView()
table.setModel(filter_proxy_model)
layout.addWidget(table)

window.show()
app.exec_()
```

You have a `QStandardItemModel` which is set as source of a `QSortFilterProxyModel` which uses the third column for filtering and uses the input of a `QLineEdit` as filtering expression. The `QSortFilterProxyModel` is used as model by a `QTableView`.

And it looks like:

[image: No filtering]

[image: Filtering]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I cant use the table.setModel method since i'm using it in calss and its private method, what can I do about it?

Comment: I changed my table to QTableView and it works! but there is a way to do it with QTableWidget?

Comment: @snir.tur You cannot use a QTableWidget because it has a non-changeable inbuilt model. QTableView is the perfect substitution. Either use it or you cannot do what you want.

Comment: How do you filter for WHOLE word? For example you have "A" and get "Apple" and "Ananas", I want it to have to be = "Apple".