# SortFilterProxyModel in Qt with qml model

Tags: qt, qml, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have a problem with `sortFilterProxyModel` of QT's table model/view.

When I type the word to search from the table which is filled by model(ListModel) in QML than it sorted right and result is also accordingly (like correct name of the file and it's Id ) but when I clicked the row to get index, it shows from zero to display the content because of it's property of re-indexing but I don't want because of it's re-indexing I received wrong `fileId` as I set.

I am stuck with this problem. How can I leave it out?

Comment: Not sure if I understood you correctly, but there is: `QSortFilterProxyModel::mapToSource(QModelIndex index)`

Comment: No not using this, because I am using Qml so the sortFilterProxyModel use directly there. and the method   "QObject *SortFilterProxyModel::source() const   //PNU
{
    //qDebug()<<"sourceOfSortfileterProxyModel : "<<source();
    return sourceModel();
}"     calling there directly

Comment: How about this answer over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34252413/how-to-create-a-filter-for-qtablewidget/34286827#34286827 ?
I don't know what programming language do you use. The link is for python. But, you can have an idea.

Answer (score 2):

I face the same issue and got it to work by doing this:

In your sortfilterproxy.h add a public slot function:

```
public slots:
    int getModelIndex(int);
```

In your sortfilterproxy.cpp implement this function:

```
int SortFilterProxyModel::getModelIndex(int row)
{
     QModelIndex sourceIndex = mapToSource(this->index(row, 0));
    return sourceIndex.row();//this returns an integer
}
```

Now on your TableView in QML you can do this:

```
  onCurrentRowChanged: 
  {
   var currentIndex = currentRow;
   console.log(currentIndex);
   var rowModelIndex= proxyModel.getModelIndex(currentIndex);
   console.log(rowModelIndex);
...
```

Hope this helps.

Michael

Comment: Thanks, this works for me, however I am puzzled why this is neccessary. `mapToSource(index)` should provide the same functionality, however doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Caught the same problem as you.
Playing around 
*QtQuick TableView Example* and 
[*Qt Blog note*](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2014/04/16/qt-weekly-6-sorting-and-filtering-a-tableview)

I've found a [QTBUG-50019](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-50019) (TableView: Track selection by the item and not by the index of the item).
Seems it's not going to be resolved soon.

As alternative you could create an additional index in your Table/List View and juggle them for self aims like this

```
ListView {
    id: root

    property real selectedIndex: -1
    ...
    delegate: Item {
            color: (index === root.selectedIndex) 
                   ? parent.color = "gray" 
                   : parent.color = root.color

            Connections {
                target: root

                onSelectedIndexChanged: {
                    if(index === root.selectedIndex)
                        root.currentIndex = index
                }
            }

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: root.selectedIndex = index
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex Makarov, for you suggestion.  But I did resolve it oneself by assigning same role as fileId column so now whenever I click on button to open the file it pick-ups right fileId, Now I no need to get it's index

Comment: You should add your solution as update to original question and make this topic more useful for others.